# OpenTK Picking sample crashing

Tags: c#, opentk

I am going through OpenTK (opentk-2010-10-06.exe) sample code which is provided with the OpenTK installation. I am interested on picking example, but it crashes. but other samples are working. What is the problem? Does anybody come across this problem. Please help

I couldn't post the image here, but the exception is about OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsErrorException

Comment: Try the latest SVN version and the this github repo: https://github.com/andykorth/opentk

The 2010 release is really old, latest SVN version is still very stable, and the github should also be stable. And if you could post the entire stack trace that would be helpful

Comment: @RobertRouhani   

A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> OpenTK.Graphics.GraphicsErrorException: InvalidEnum
   at OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.ErrorHelper.CheckErrors() in C:\Users\PNPAHM\Documents\OpenTK\1.0\Source\OpenTK\Graphics\OpenGL\ErrorHelper.cs:line 118
   at OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.ErrorHelper.Dispose() in C:\Users\PN\Documents\OpenTK\1.0\Source\OpenTK\Graphics\OpenGL\ErrorHelper.cs:line 129

Comment: Looks like an invalid enum... the examples should have a debug log somewhere that will tell you exactly when this invalid enum error occurs.

Comment: @RobertRouhani, It is great that OpenTK is continued by somebody. I have downloaded the code and compiled it . It crashed and gave a message that "vshost-clr2.exe has stopped working" Is it because I am using 32 bit operating system?. I will look in to the enum problem and p[ost an answer here. It may be useful for others

Comment: @RobertRouhani I have found something interesting. One time it displayed in my machine same as this in opentk forum http://www.opentk.com/node/2913

Comment: I am using Intel graphic card, and the problem from graphic card seems. Please update me if anybody knows the answer

Comment: From that thread, it looks like the picking example is using a trick that either causes a driver bug in the Intel implementation or simply is not supported by the card...

Comment: @RobertRouhani Yes Exactly :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thread give the answer (opentk.com/node/2913 ). 
If you want to develop a sample/ or tryout picking mechanism, select the redbook sample (from Tao) and change it to OpenTK commands, It is very simple and direct :-)